# how to check whether my userscloud links got deleted or not at once?

Tags: file, hosting

Actually my problem is: I upload lot of files to userscloud.com, sometimes my files got taken down due to DMCA, checking each link is time taking process, & also userscloud not showing any files in "DMCA Files" tab after removing my file, actually it should show, so how to check whether my userscloud links a.k.a files got deleted or not at once?

Comment: Guys if it is off topic then won't earn 3 up votes, please try to remove on-hold on this question. You guys are expert in hosting programming so answer my question.